# How do I find out what my different (virtual) network interfaces are, and what service created them?

Tags: networking

I would like to "clean up" in the network interfaces. If I run `ip addr`, i get the following list (see bottom of post).

#2 and #3 are my 2 physical NICs (#2 currently unplugged), and I have created #5 and #6 myself in my netplan config. #10 (`docker0`) also makes sense to me.

However, most of the others are a complete mystery to me (e.g., all the virtual ethernets).

Is there a way to see which service created them, and if they are in use? Essentially, whether I can safely delete them. I'm a bit hesitant to just start `sudo ip link delete INTERFACE` without knowing more about them.

Output of `brctl show`:

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-870fc0691e90     8000.0242670e67e3   no      veth3c7caf7
br-c43d0708a05e     8000.0242db5a4d9f   no      veth447ed70
br-f32d9d8a97b7     8000.024225ae37b1   no      veth0174902
                            veth0b62e6b
                            veth3965e56
                            veth52593cf
                            veth589e856
                            veth6acd0d3
                            veth74d8b27
                            vethb06ec0c
                            vethb71f188
                            vethcd3e855
                            vethe5a1aae
                            vetheb8ac27
                            vethff7a086
br0     8000.329db9331ed5   yes     eno1
                            vnet0
docker0     8000.0242c78c0ee3   no
virbr0      8000.5254002797d6   yes
```

Output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:5e:c6:43:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0f0
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:5e:c6:43:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0f1
4: enx02215eca3baf: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:21:5e:ca:3b:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:9d:b9:33:1e:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.30.21/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.30.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 76838sec preferred_lft 76838sec
    inet6 fe80::309d:b9ff:fe33:1ed5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vlan40@eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:5e:c6:43:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:27:97:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:26:69:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe26:6940/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: br-870fc0691e90: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:67:0e:67:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-870fc0691e90
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:67ff:fe0e:67e3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:c7:8c:0e:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: br-c43d0708a05e: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:db:5a:4d:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.11.0.1/24 brd 172.11.0.255 scope global br-c43d0708a05e
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:dbff:fe5a:4d9f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: br-f32d9d8a97b7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:25:ae:37:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-f32d9d8a97b7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:25ff:feae:37b1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: vethb06ec0c@if13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether 72:08:f7:98:75:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::7008:f7ff:fe98:75d2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: veth3c7caf7@if15: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-870fc0691e90 state UP group default
    link/ether 2a:fb:a7:23:ef:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::28fb:a7ff:fe23:efa5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: veth447ed70@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-c43d0708a05e state UP group default
    link/ether ca:3a:29:a8:ba:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::c83a:29ff:fea8:babd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
20: vethe5a1aae@if19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether a2:c1:db:43:c0:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::a0c1:dbff:fe43:c0bd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: veth52593cf@if21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether ca:67:51:81:95:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::c867:51ff:fe81:95c5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
24: veth74d8b27@if23: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether 92:fa:e9:b0:13:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::90fa:e9ff:feb0:13d7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
26: vethb71f188@if25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether 0e:0e:da:df:15:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::c0e:daff:fedf:1598/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
28: veth0174902@if27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether 7e:e0:b1:76:d9:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
    inet6 fe80::7ce0:b1ff:fe76:d947/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: veth3965e56@if29: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether b2:ca:05:df:1c:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 9
    inet6 fe80::b0ca:5ff:fedf:1caf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: vethff7a086@if33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether 6a:97:34:da:5d:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 10
    inet6 fe80::6897:34ff:feda:5d2f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
36: vetheb8ac27@if35: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether f2:d3:47:65:5c:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 11
    inet6 fe80::f0d3:47ff:fe65:5cb0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
38: veth0b62e6b@if37: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether 4e:05:42:a2:62:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 12
    inet6 fe80::4c05:42ff:fea2:623d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
40: veth6acd0d3@if39: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether b2:7e:7c:8c:85:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 13
    inet6 fe80::b07e:7cff:fe8c:85b3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
42: veth589e856@if41: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether 0a:4e:7c:29:ba:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 14
    inet6 fe80::84e:7cff:fe29:ba3a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
72: vethcd3e855@if71: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f32d9d8a97b7 state UP group default
    link/ether f6:24:c0:75:e6:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 8
    inet6 fe80::f424:c0ff:fe75:e624/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is Ubuntu server LTS 22.04.

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu server LTS 22.04 (updated post)

Comment: Are you using `docker compose` commands with YAMLs?  Because those create individual bridges, and *sometimes* create virtual ethernet devices that get attached to containers.  If you have a lot of Docker containers running then I would suggest you take them all down and see if the `veth`s go away.

Comment: That (`docker-compose down`) took me from 27 to 9 interfaces. Still not sure about `enx02215eca3baf`, but I'm certainly close enough that if you, @ThomasWard, create an answer with this I'd accept that.

Comment: @Aephir that's a physical interface.  Either an ethernet adapter or a misidentified wireless dongle, etc.  And it has the MAC of 02:21:5e:ca:3b:af.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use docker or containers or even Virtual machines, each container or system has to have a virtual ethernet device that connects to bridges.

You show you use Docker, which also is likely why you have the bridges running, because you're using `docker-compose`.  Each container has its own `veth` on the host system that maps to the container's networking.  The more Docker containers you run, the more `veth` devices that will spawn.

If you do a `docker-compose down` and shut all your Docker containers down/off, the number of `veth` devices will decrease drastically.

---

Note that `enx` devices are devices ID'd by mac address.

Per the Predictable Network Interface Naming systems (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) that SystemD uses, you can find this out pretty easy:

> 1. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board devices (example: eno1)
> 2. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: ens1)
> 3. Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0)
> 4. **Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example: enx78e7d1ea46da)**
> 5. Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: eth0)

(emphasis mine)

Your `enx` device is a physical interface with the MAC address of 02:21:5E:CA:3B:AF and is installed on your system somewhere, whether internally on the system or externally via a USB dongle or such is impossible to tell.